# Calling generic method by passing parameters?

Tags: java, generics

I have below Generic method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public <T extends MyObject> T  getResult(Class<T> class, String id){

      //Have some logic

    }
}
```

As it is a generic method what kind of parameters do i need to pass?

I mean which parameters do i need to pass to the method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invoke your method like below

```
MyObject result = getResult(MyObject.class, "myId");
```

Here is a shot explaination of your method `getResult`

- *Param 1* - takes any class of type `MyObject`
- *Param 2* - takes any String
- *Retruns* - an Object of type `MyObject`.

Answer (score 2):

You need some class extending MyObject:

```
class A extends MyObject { ... }
```

If you have this, you can call the method like so:

```
A a = myClass.getResult(A.class, "id");
```

You get an instance of A  back.

You may also skip creating class A and use MyObject directly, since the constraint `<T extends MyObject>` makes `T` match every class that extends MyObject, including the class MyObject itself.

Answer (score 0):

Given this definition

```
public <T extends MyObject> T  getResult(Class<T> class, String id)
```

You need to pass the class of an Object of type (or a sub-type of) MyObject and String. Something like `getResult(MyObject.class, "pickles");`. The method then must return an instance of MyObject (or a sub-class).